# Migrating Users from one AWS Cognito Pool to another keeping the CognitoId/Sub value

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

A recent-ish release of AWS Cognito has now allowed for case insensitivity for username input however you can't enable it on a current User Pool and requires to create a new User Pool and then migrate the users to it...

So, I've created a new user pool and have a Migration lambda working successfully but I've hit one final issue. We use the CognitoId as a Primary Key within our other systems and now when I migrate the from UserPool A to UserPool B, it creates a new CognitoId and it doesn't seem possible (from what I can see) to manually set the CognitoId / Sub as the value from the previous pool in the new pool.

Has anyone come across this before and have a work around as it's not easily feasible to update all references to a new key. (The new CognitoId isn't returned to any function in the process either)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I've got the same issue (trying to get away for case sensitive emails) but need to keep the ids

Comment: I had to do a horrible work around whereby I updated all my references across the database when the user migration trigger happened. Create a new user, and update the user data from the old ID. I needed to create a new field on the cognito instance of the old cognito id to track it across the lambdas.

Answer (score 0):

Cognito Sub is generated internally by the service when the user is created. [It is immutable and cannot be assigned a new value.](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248829)
One approach to store "sub" from the old userpool could be to store it in a [custom attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-settings-attributes.html#user-pool-settings-custom-attributes) of new userpool. You can check for the custom attribute claim in the ID token to access the user data from your existing system.

> Custom attribute is only available in [Cognito ID token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token). If you are currently using Cognito access token with your other systems, this approach won't work for you.