# What to use as a primary key with AWS Cognito for handling backups and recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

For a little backstory, we're currently in the middle of migrating a Cognito user pool to a new one, due to several outdated configuration properties we need to update.  To do this, we are planning on using a Cognito Lambda trigger to handle the migration.

However, the big problem we're running into is that we use the `sub` attribute as an ID for the user.  According to [AWS](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248829), this value is globally unique across all user pools.  This means that we cannot migrate the `sub` attribute to a new pool, since it would then no longer be unique.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378173/migrating-users-from-one-aws-cognito-pool-to-another-keeping-the-cognitoid-sub-v) question and answer, they indicate that the `sub` attribute is the correct attribute to use for a primary key.  However, in the event of a disaster like a deleted or corrupted pool, using the `sub` attribute as a primary key doesn't work.  If you import users to a backup pool, the `sub`'s will be different and your primary key will be lost.

At this point, I should mention that we are using the Access token for the "groups", which does **not** contain any custom attributes, so adding the primary key to the custom attributes doesn't work for us.

So to finally get to my question, what *should* we be using for a primary key with AWS Cognito so we don't run into this pitfall again?

Comment: Do you mean you are using sub as primary key in a database and are worried that if you use sub and need to migrate the database will have to be updated with new sub?

Comment: Yes, exactly @NinadGaikwad

Comment: Then you can have username as primary key and include sub as regular attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't quite work for us because we are using the Username and it's mutability to handle another use case.